# iAd implementation reacts differently to devices

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have implemented iAd and when running on iPad the iAd is a banner in the bottom - which is the plan.

When I run on Iphone Retina 3.5 inch: I need to move my banner up from the bottom - because when I put 
it in the bottom of the screen in the storyboard is fall outside of the screen when I run

on Iphone Retina 4 inch AND on 64 bit version:
iAd shows up as it's now placed in the storyboard, meaning it's somewhat higher up from the bottom of the screen.

I have Auto Layout enabled. Is there someway to make this go in the bottom on all iPhone devices?